# Segmentation fault 11 - network program

Tags: c, sockets, networking, segmentation-fault

This is my first attempt at writing a network program. It compiles without problems but when I run it it gives me a 'segmentation fault 11'. I'm hoping somebody could give me clue what in the code could be causing this problem.

I am new at C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{   
    ////////////      GETADDRINFO   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    memset(&hints, 0 , sizeof hints);

    hints.ai_family     = AF_UNSPEC;    //define the 'hints' strucure
    hints.ai_socktype   = SOCK_STREAM;  //define the 'hints' strucure
    hints.ai_protocol   = AI_PASSIVE;   //define the 'hints' strucure

    char *ipaddr = "127.0.0.1";
    getaddrinfo(ipaddr, "ftp", &hints, &res);

    //////////////     SOCKET     \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in info;
    int bnd  = bind( sock , res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);

    info.sin_family         = AF_INET;
    info.sin_port           = htons(10000);
    info.sin_addr.s_addr    = INADDR_ANY;   
    bzero(&(info.sin_zero),8); 


    ///////////////    CONNECT   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ 

    int conct = connect( sock, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);

    //////////////     LISTEN     \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

    int lstn = listen( sock , 4 );

    //////////////    ACCEPT    \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

    int new_fd;
    struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
    new_fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_size);

    /////////////////   SEND   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

    char *msg = "HI!";
    int len, bytes_sent;
    len = strlen(msg);
    bytes_sent = send(sock, msg, len, 0);

    //////////////// RECEIVE \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

    char burr[254];
    int cat = sizeof(burr);

    recv( sock, burr , cat , 0 );

    printf("%s", burr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to figure out the exact line where this fails, with `printf` and etc. This is how debugging works.

Comment: You aren't error checking functions that can fail, such as `getaddrinfo()` or `recv()`.  If `getaddrinfo()` is failing, it could easily account for the segmentation fault.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeeeaah, I'm guilty of lazyness. I wanted to write something fast to test it out. Thank you for the info

Comment: @jsn Gotcha. I'm usin gcc instead of a hardcore IDE. This is where one of those could come in handy, thank you for the info.

Comment: The trouble is that if you skip the error checks, you get the crashes.  Which actually makes the process slower than writing the error checks in the first place.  Make sure you've got a good error reporting library to make it easy to report errors.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good tip. I am just beginning to teach my self how to program so every piece of information is valuable to me. This is the kind of stuff that sometimes gets overlooked in books

Comment: For a rudimentary version of a relatively comprehensive error reporting package, look at [SO 13636252](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13640308/15168) or very similar code in [SO 13654397](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13664546/15168) — the first reports PIDs and the second doesn't.  Or contact me (see my profile) for the full `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` combination.

Comment: Function `getaddrinfo()` is not changing the `res` pointer, because there is no `ftp` service running on `127.0.0.1`, thats why whenever you use `res`, I will contain garbage which causes seg fault.

Comment: First,Check were do segmentation fault occurred,just run your program use `gdb`.

Answer (score 4):

The segfault occurs at the time of first `bind` because `getaddrinfo` returns error this the `res` structure is not valid.

The error returned by `getaddrinfo` is

> EAI_SOCKTYPE
>
> The  requested socket type is not supported.  This could occur, for example, if hints.ai_socktype and hints.ai_protocol are inconsistent (e.g., SOCK_DGRAM and IPPROTO_TCP, respectively).

you have set in `hints.ai_protocol = AI_PASSIVE` which is not correct. The manual says:

> ai_protocol This field specifies the protocol for the returned socket addresses.  Specifying 0 in this field indicates that socket addresses with any protocol can be returned by getaddrinfo().

So you should set it to 0 if you want to get any protocol.

This although removes the segfault but the program is messy and not correct.

Also to note:

You are using the listener socket to send and receive. You should use the socket returned by `accept` which is `new_fd` in your code to `send` and `recv` as that is the channel established between.

You have defined and initialized the structure `info` and never used it.

Have a look at this this might help you to get quickly into sockets: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/